# Read a file and parse its content

Tags: angular, angular5

I have file upload control which holds the selected file as below,

```
<div class="Block">
  <label id="lbl">File </label>
  <input #fileInput type='file'/>
</div>
```

I have a submit button as below,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
     (click)="uploadDocument()">Upload File</button>
```

When I select a file and click on the upload button the file I need the contents inside the file without sending it to the server and reading from there.

Note: Type of file will be `csv`

Comment: @Kartik had you get the solution for your problem.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can use `FileReader` in javascript to achieve this as its a `csv` file

Add a file change event to store the file in a object as below,

```html
<div class="Block">
  <label id="lbl">Code </label>
  <input type='file' (change)="fileChanged($event)">

</div>
```

The function should set the file to an object which is used later

```ts
file:any;
fileChanged(e) {
    this.file = e.target.files[0];
}
```

When the submit button is clicked you can use the `readAsText()` method of `FileReader` in javascript to get the content as below,

```ts
uploadDocument(file) {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
      console.log(fileReader.result);
    }
    fileReader.readAsText(this.file);
}
```

**Note**: `onload` event will be fired after the content is read so your logic should be inside the `onLoad` function.

Comment: How can I save the records that I parsed into fileReader into a hashmap in typescript?

Comment: Do we need to remove the `FileReader` event listeners we subscribe to?

Comment: @arvind how can i read or store file content into some array,so that I can use those content into some other positon.

Comment: fileReader.readAsText() gives an error: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'. I have tried many solutions but nothing seems to work. What should i do?

Answer (score 15):

you pull the file out of the input and use the FileReader API

```
readFile(file: File) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
        console.log(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Comment: how can i read or store file content into some array,so that I can use those content into some other positon.

Comment: var lines = myReader.result.split('\n'); The line above in my answer, does just that. It splits the content of the file into an array.

Answer (score 12):

if you want to make it as function you can do

```
    readFileContent(file: File): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
            if (!file) {
                resolve('');
            }

            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (e) => {
                const text = reader.result.toString();
                resolve(text);

            };

            reader.readAsText(file);
        });
    }
```

then

```
const fileContent = await readFileContent(file);
```

Answer (score 7):

For those asking how to get string data after reading it, the data is in the `result` property of `fileReader`. Check the code sample below.

```
    let fileString:any= "";

    uploadDocument(file) {
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = (e) => {
           //console.log(myReader.result);
           // Entire file
           console.log(myReader.result);

           // By lines
           var lines = myReader.result.split('\n');
           for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
               console.log(lines[line]);
           }

           this.fileString = myReader.result;
        };

        fileReader.readAsText(this.file);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> it works, try like this..

```
var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend =(e) =>{
          var result = reader.result; 
              console.log(i+'/'+result)
              this.file64.push(result)
        };  
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a modern native alternative: [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) implements [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), so we can call Blob.text().

```
async function readText(event) {
  const file = event.target.files.item(0)
  const text = await file.text();
  
  document.getElementById("output").innerText = text
}
```